# Can't connect to MySQL Workbench server with XAMPP installed

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I was using MySQL Workbench 5.7 about a year ago, and since then I have used XAMPP. 1.8.3 and Microsoft Management Sever 2017. Recently, I updated to workbench 6.3

I can't get the server started on workbench even though I am using port 3307 and the phpMyAdmin for is using port 3306. When I start the instance on workbench and try to start the server I get

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
```

There is no password because in the XAMPP > mysql > bin the my.ini file looks like this:

```
# password       = your_password
 port            = 3306
 socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

I can't find a similar file in the program files for workbench.

Comment: Just for the records: MySQL Workbench is a client application, not a server. You cannot connect **to** it, but you can use it to connect to a MySQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. I switched to port 3306 on MySQL workbench and used the password for MySQL in XAMPP and then start the server on XAMPP.